# Getting sometimes curl_setopt_array(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in strange place

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, curl

**Error:** curl_setopt_array(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource

**Input:**

```
countries   
array:6 [
  0 => "sve"
  1 => "nld"
  2 => "lvi"
  3 => "lth"
  4 => "eti"
  5 => "hrv"
]
date_from   
"01.09.2018"
date_to 
"30.09.2018"
```

I am just iterating through the countries and call retrieveData method.

It's crashes after he wrote json to the file, on `return $data`. I ran more then 10 times. And sometimes he managed to write only 1 file (sve), sometimes 2 (sve, nld) and once he wrote 3...

It's very strange problem.

**Stack trace:**

[remaining stacktrace](https://ibb.co/iudCHK)

```
Elasticsearch\Helper\Iterators\SearchResponseIterator __destruct
…\app\Managers\XXX\XXX.php 

App\Managers\XXX\XXX retriveData
…\app\Http\Controllers\ManagersController.php
```

**Managers controller:**

```
foreach ($countries_to_retrieve as $country) {
    $this->all_countries_data[$country] = XXX::retriveData($country, $request->date_from, $request->date_to);
}
```

**XXX.php:**

[See whole class](https://pastebin.com/hAKJAMjE)

```
public static function retriveData($country, $from, $to): array {

    ...

    if (!in_array($folder, Storage::directories())) {
        Storage::makeDirectory($folder);
    }
    Storage::put($folder . '\\' . $country . $from . $to, json_encode($data));

    return $data; <----- HERE is exception
}
```

Is there is ideas, how do I continue to investigate the issue?

P.S. forgot to say, that this maybe related to **PHP version**, our production is on 5.6, but now we are migrating to 5.7, and we are testing everything on 5.7.
And this functionality is working on production, but on localhost we have such problem.

Comment: how come that $data variable is popping up suddenly in the function ?

Comment: try to print the result of json_encode($data)

Comment: @syam, I am collecting this $data, i haven't put all the code of retriveData , i put ... (3 dots). There is just simple json code.

Comment: I have removed return $data; and now he throws exception on last bracket of the method..

Comment: since you have not given complete idea about the code, we can only guess, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442999/getting-curl-error-2-is-not-a-valid-curl-handle-resource-while-fetching-all-u . Hope it helps you.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hAKJAMjE

Comment: how the curl is getting called ?

Comment: That the question. I am not calling curl :)

Comment: For this elastic search i think internally its calling curl or some api, which package are you using for that.

Comment: is it this one https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch

Comment: yes, this one, but it uses elasticsearch/elasticsearch official library, I think something wrong with that.

Comment: yes, their code seems to have broken, can you create a issue on their GitHub repo, so that they will also know their code broke